# python WSGI with long running process

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to write a simple WSGI-compliant application that responds to a HTTP POST, sends some data to the server, **closes the connection**, and
continues to execute for a few more seconds.

It's a longer running, but not LONG running process.  I have to respond and close the connection within 3 seconds (Slack) but my program may take 5 or so seconds to actually run.  I can afford to run with enough WSGI processes to handle the load even at 5 seconds.

Here's an example:

```
import time

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    yield "foo\n".encode()
    # we're done responding to the server, close the connection

    time.sleep(5)
    with open('/tmp/foo', 'w') as stream:
        stream.write('output stuff\n')
```

In this example, the yield correctly flushes things, but I'd like to continue executing.  I could do a fork and then return() in the parent,
as I would were this a CGI script, but I'm not happy about having all
that unclosed WSGI state.

I'm using Python 3.5 and mod_wsgi for testing, but I'd like this to be generic/compliant.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve it the way you wanted, but do you know that you can respond with an empty response, and later do a request to the `response_url` they give you?

Comment: @L3viathan that's exactly what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the code was trivial, I'll answer this myself:

```
@app.route("/foo", methods=['POST'])
def slack_request():
    """Process a slash-command POST request from Slack"""
    query = QuerySlack(app.config, app.mdb, reporter)
    job = Thread(target=query, args=(response.form['query'],))
    job.start()
    try:
        return "processing {}...".format(' '.join(response.form['query']))
    except (ReportError, QueryError) as err:
        return str(err)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about a thread pool model? You can have a producer-consumer queue. Just post to the queue from the WSGI application and return immediately. The work will be done in a different thread.